# Knockout JS foreach binding overwrite values with last index value

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I want to display data from observable array to views. When I'm using foreach binding, the value showed all replaced by last index value, as in i want to show data A, B, C but it shows C, C, C
If the data gives value A, B then it shows B, B
I don't know what's wrong since this is the first time i get this problem when using foreach

This is the view that I used. Foreach departments showing just fine, but coaOperasional and detailOperasional is not.

```js
function AddDepartmentModel(deptname, deptcode, coaop) {
  var self = this;
  self.deptname = ko.observable(deptname);
  self.deptcode = ko.observable(deptcode);
  self.coaOperasional = ko.observableArray([]);

  $(coaop).each(function(key, item) {
    self.coaOperasional.push(new AddCoaOperasional(item.type, item.detail));
  });

  self.totalOperasional = ko.computed(function() {
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < self.coaOperasional().length; i++) {
      if (!jQuery.isEmptyObject(self.coaOperasional()[i])) {
        for (var j = 0; j < self.coaOperasional()[i].detailOperasional().length; j++) {
          total += parseFloat(removePeriod(self.coaOperasional()[i].detailOperasional()[j].totalop(), ","));
        }
      }
    }
    return addPeriod(total, ",")
  });
}

function AddCoaOperasional(type, detail) {
  var self = this;
  self.optype = ko.observable(type);
  self.detailOperasional = ko.observableArray([]);
  $(detail).each(function(key, item) {
    self.detailOperasional.push(new AddDetailOperasional(item.code, item.coa, item.total, item.parent));
  });

  self.optypetotal = ko.computed(function() {
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < self.detailOperasional().length; i++) {
      var tamptot = self.detailOperasional()[i].totalop();
      tamptot = tamptot.replace("<b>", "");
      tamptot = tamptot.replace("</b>", "");
      total += parseFloat(removePeriod(tamptot, ","));
    }
    return addPeriod(total, ",")
  });
}

function AddDetailOperasional(code, coa, total, parent) {
  var self = this;
  if (parent == "yes") {
    self.codeop = ko.observable("");
    self.coaop = ko.observable("<b>" + coa + "</b>");
    self.totalop = ko.observable("<b>" + addPeriod(Math.abs(total), ",") + "</b>");
  } else {
    self.codeop = ko.observable(code);
    self.coaop = ko.observable(coa);
    self.totalop = ko.observable(addPeriod(Math.abs(total), ","));
  }
}

function MainModel() {
  var self = this;
  var listdept = getData();
  self.departments = ko.observableArray();

  listdept.map(function(i) {
    self.departments.push(new AddDepartmentModel(i.deptname, i.deptcode, i.operasional));
  });
}

var vm = new MainModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);

function addPeriod(num, period) {
    return num.toFixed(2).replace('.', period);
}
function removePeriod(str, period) {
    return +str.replace(period, '.');
}


function getData() {
  return [{
    "deptname": "LEARNING JOURNEY",
    "deptcode": "1",
    "operasional": [
      {
        "type": "PENDAPATAN OPERASIONAL",
        "detail": [
          {
            "coa": "PENDAPATAN UANG SEKOLAH BRUTO",
            "code": "4.1.01.01",
            "total": "0.00",
            "parent": "no"
          },
          {
            "coa": "POTONGAN UANG SEKOLAH",
            "code": "4.1.01.91",
            "total": "0.00",
            "parent": "no"
          },
          {
            "coa": "PENDAPATAN UANG SEKOLAH NETO",
            "code": "4.1.01",
            "total": "0.00",
            "parent": "yes"
          },
          {
            "coa": "PENDAPATAN UANG KEGIATAN BRUTO",
            "code": "4.1.02.01",
            "total": "0.00",
            "parent": "no"
          },
          {
            "coa": "POTONGAN UANG KEGIATAN",
            "code": "4.1.02.91",
            "total": "0.00",
            "parent": "no"
          },
          {
            "coa": "PENDAPATAN UANG KEGIATAN NETO",
            "code": "4.1.02",
            "total": "0.00",
            "parent": "yes"
          },
        ]
      },
      {
        "type": "BEBAN OPERASIONAL",
        "detail": [
          {
            "coa": "BEBAN REMUNERASI",
            "code": "5.1.01.01",
            "total": "0.00",
            "parent": "no"
          },
          {
            "coa": "BEBAN SEKOLAH",
            "code": "5.1.01",
            "total": "0.00",
            "parent": "yes"
          },
          {
            "coa": "BEBAN ADMINISTRASI KESISWAAN",
            "code": "5.1.02.01",
            "total": "0.00",
            "parent": "no"
          },
          {
            "coa": "BEBAN ASURANSI SISWA",
            "code": "5.1.02.02",
            "total": "0.00",
            "parent": "no"
          },
          {
            "coa": "BEBAN PENGHAPUSAN",
            "code": "5.2.91",
            "total": "0.00",
            "parent": "yes"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "pajak": "0.00"
  }];
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr data-bind="foreach: departments">
      <td style="vertical-align:top">
        <table class='table table-striped nowrap'>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th colspan="2" data-bind="visible: $index() == 0"></th>
              <th style="width:400px"><span data-bind="text: deptname">Nama Dept</span></th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="3">
                <table class='table table-striped nowrap' data-bind="foreach: coaOperasional" style="width: 100%">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td colspan="2" data-bind="visible: $parentContext.$index() == 0">
                        <b><span data-bind="text: optype">Tipe</span></b>
                      </td>
                      <td><b>&nbsp;</b></td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                  <tbody data-bind="foreach: detailOperasional">
                    <tr>
                      <td data-bind="text: codeop,visible: $parentContext.$parentContext.$index() == 0">### code ###</td>
                      <td data-bind="html: coaop,visible: $parentContext.$parentContext.$index() == 0">### coa ###</td>
                      <td data-bind="html: totalop">0</td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td data-bind="visible: $parentContext.$index() == 0"></td>
                      <td data-bind="visible: $parentContext.$index() == 0"><b>JUMLAH <span data-bind="text: optype">Tipe</span></b></td>
                      <td><b><span data-bind="text: optypetotal"></span></b></td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td data-bind="visible: $index() == 0" colspan="2"><b>SURPLUS (DEFISIT) OPERASIONAL</b></td>
              <td><b><span data-bind="text: totalOperasional"></span></b></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: sorry, just updated it

Comment: Can you also add a (minimal!) sample of `data`?

Comment: added sample of data

Comment: I've edited your question so that the code sample stops throwing errors. For your next question, please *start* with something like this. Nobody can just guess your data and then imagine where your issue comes from. Code that actually reproduces your issure is a basic requirement on Stack Overflow. Now please make the final changes so that the code sample actually behaves the way you describe.

Answer (score 2):

A fundamental mistake in your approach is that you try to format your data *in your viewmodel*, e.g. formatting financial values or making things bold.

Never do that.

All formatting is supposed to happen in the view, either through CSS, or through bindings. It's *much* easier to create a [custom binding handler](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html) that formats financial values for display, than to constantly format and un-format numbers in the model like you currently do.

Other remarks:

- Showing or hiding certain things (like `code` for a certain detail record) based on some condition (e.g. `parent` or not) is also best done in the view. It's easy to use `if:` or `ifnot:` for this.
- I don't understand the purpose of your `visible: $parentContext.$index() == 0` checks at all. The way you do that, the `$index` *always* is 0, so these do exactly nothing. I've removed them from the view below.
- Keep the property names consistent, e.g. it's unnecessary and confusing to call a property `codeop` in your viewmodel, when it's actually called `code` in your model.
- Making viewmodel constructors that take one single `data` parameter, instead of 3 or more individual parameters, helps a lot with keeping the code clean, too.
- You don't need jQuery to do loops. JavaScript can do loops just fine on its own. I've removed all jQuery references.
- You don't really need `var self = this;` anymore in modern JS. When you work with arrow functions in your viewmodels, `this` will keep its meaning in methods and helper functions.

Compare how easy the viewmodels AND the view become when you do things where you're supposed to do them (I can't reproduce the `foreach:` issue you speak of):

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.currency = {
  // display numbers with 2 decimal digits, comma and parentheses if negative
  update: (element, valueAccessor) => {
    const value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
    const formatted = Math.abs(value).toFixed(2).replace('.', ',');
    element.textContent = value < 0 ? '(' + formatted + ')' : formatted;
  }
};

// helper to calculate a grand total across array items
const sumProperty = (array, prop) => array.reduce((total, item) => total + ko.unwrap(item[prop]), 0);

function MainModel(data) {
  this.departments = ko.observableArray(data.departments.map(item => new Department(item)));
}

function Department(data) {
  this.deptname = ko.observable(data.deptname);
  this.deptcode = ko.observable(data.deptcode);
  this.operasional = ko.observableArray(data.operasional.map(item => new Operasional(item)));
  this.total = ko.pureComputed(() => sumProperty(this.operasional(), 'total'));
}

function Operasional(data) {
  this.type = ko.observable(data.type);
  this.detail = ko.observableArray(data.detail.map(item => new DetailOperasional(item)));
  this.total = ko.pureComputed(() => sumProperty(this.detail(), 'total'));
}

function DetailOperasional(data) {
  this.code = ko.observable(data.code);
  this.coa = ko.observable(data.coa);
  this.parent = ko.observable(data.parent === 'yes');
  this.total = ko.observable(+data.total);
}

getData().then(data => {
  ko.applyBindings(new MainModel(data));
});

function getData() {
  return Promise.resolve({
    "departments": [{
        "deptname": "LEARNING JOURNEY",
        "deptcode": "1",
        "operasional": [
          {
            "type": "PENDAPATAN OPERASIONAL",
            "detail": [
              {
                "coa": "PENDAPATAN UANG SEKOLAH BRUTO",
                "code": "4.1.01.01",
                "total": "100.00",
                "parent": "no"
              },
              {
                "coa": "POTONGAN UANG SEKOLAH",
                "code": "4.1.01.91",
                "total": "10.00",
                "parent": "no"
              },
              {
                "coa": "PENDAPATAN UANG SEKOLAH NETO",
                "code": "4.1.01",
                "total": "200.00",
                "parent": "yes"
              },
              {
                "coa": "PENDAPATAN UANG KEGIATAN BRUTO",
                "code": "4.1.02.01",
                "total": "220.00",
                "parent": "no"
              },
              {
                "coa": "POTONGAN UANG KEGIATAN",
                "code": "4.1.02.91",
                "total": "30.00",
                "parent": "no"
              },
              {
                "coa": "PENDAPATAN UANG KEGIATAN NETO",
                "code": "4.1.02",
                "total": "125.00",
                "parent": "yes"
              },
            ]
          },
          {
            "type": "BEBAN OPERASIONAL",
            "detail": [
              {
                "coa": "BEBAN REMUNERASI",
                "code": "5.1.01.01",
                "total": "-150.00",
                "parent": "no"
              },
              {
                "coa": "BEBAN SEKOLAH",
                "code": "5.1.01",
                "total": "-100.00",
                "parent": "yes"
              },
              {
                "coa": "BEBAN ADMINISTRASI KESISWAAN",
                "code": "5.1.02.01",
                "total": "-50.00",
                "parent": "no"
              },
              {
                "coa": "BEBAN ASURANSI SISWA",
                "code": "5.1.02.02",
                "total": "-25.00",
                "parent": "no"
              },
              {
                "coa": "BEBAN PENGHAPUSAN",
                "code": "5.2.91",
                "total": "-300.00",
                "parent": "yes"
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "pajak": "0.00"
      }
    ]
  });
}
```

```css
.table {
  empty-cells: show;
}
.top {
  vertical-align: top;
}
.r {
  text-align: right;
}
.b {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.nowrap {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<table width="100%">
  <tbody>
    <tr data-bind="foreach: departments">
      <td class="top">
        <table class="table table-striped nowrap" width="100%">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th colspan="3"><span data-bind="text: deptname"></span></th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="3">
                <table class='table table-striped nowrap' data-bind="foreach: operasional" width="100%">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr class="b">
                      <td colspan="2"><span data-bind="text: type"></span></td>
                      <td></td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                  <tbody data-bind="foreach: detail">
                    <tr data-bind="css: {b: parent}">
                      <td data-bind="ifnot: parent"><span data-bind="text: code"></span></td>
                      <td><span data-bind="text: coa"></span></td>
                      <td class="r"><span data-bind="currency: total"></span></td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                  <tbody>
                    <tr class="b">
                      <td></td>
                      <td>JUMLAH <span data-bind="text: type"></span></td>
                      <td class="r"><span data-bind="currency: total"></span></td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="b">
              <td colspan="2">SURPLUS (DEFISIT) OPERASIONAL</td>
              <td class="r"><span data-bind="currency: total"></span></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thank you for making this so much cleaner, gonna try changing mine based on this
--besides operasional, i have 2 more data with similar property, thats why i differentiate them by using codeop, codenop etc, but since it will be to long, i just show 1 of them here
--about the visible parent index, I use it because i want to show something like department header that only showing once (as in works only for index 0), sorry if its confusing

Comment: expected result is like this https://ibb.co/dPJJhWc

Comment: @DewiGriselda My result looks exactly like that image. Have you pressed "Run code snippet" above and looked at it?

Comment: yeah, i look at it already. I make an example of the difference here
https://ibb.co/ZVH7VTK

Comment: and thank you very much that you keep responding on this

Comment: when i only use operasional, it shows fine, but if i add 2 similar other, nonoperasional and tunjang then it gives the same error